# Where is Wine-1.5 installed?

Tags: package-management, wine

I installed Wine-1.5 with these commands in the terminal >>

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

After it downloaded some files, it got installed and I closed the terminal...but what the problem is that > I cannot find the Wine icon for the application anywhere. I went to 'Ubuntu Software Center' and looked through installed files and it wasn't there :/?.
So I've decided to download it via 'Ubuntu Software Center' but can anyone tell me how to delete the files it downloaded using terminal cause it turns out to be a waste of space for my PC.

Comment: try **$whereis wine**

Comment: You could also try **$sudo apt-get remove wi**<hit tab twice>

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Remove the PPA, don't manually edit your filesytem: http://askubuntu.com/a/91660/24694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see whole listing of files wine1.5 installed as that (from command line):

```
dpkg -L wine1.5 | less
```

Or if you need just where is executable:

```
which wine
```

If you need to see it's attributes too:

```
ls -la `which wine`
```

Comment: Wine-1.5 removed successfully. Later on I re-installed it but this time using 'Ubuntu Software Center' and it WORKED!! :D
Thanks for the help guys :)